# Trying to make daily covid update

Tags: python, time

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
today = datetime.today()
today = today.isoformat()

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.covid19api.com")
payload = ''
headers = {}
conn.request("GET", "/live/country/qatar/status/confirmed/date/",today, payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

I'm trying to make it so that it would send a get request to the api every day as an update, but i keep getting this error after adding the today variable 
`TypeError: request() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given`

Comment: In your `request` call, the date should be part of the URL according to the API. So instead of `"/live/country/qatar/status/confirmed/date/",today,` try `"/live/country/qatar/status/confirmed/date/"+today,`. The date format may need to be adjusted as well to meet the requirements of the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `request` method under [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request) takes only 4 parameters.  You'll have to concatenate the date parameter to the URL. Not as a parameter to the request method.

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()
today = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.covid19api.com")
payload = ''
headers = {}
conn.request("GET", "/live/country/india/status/confirmed/date/{0}".format(today), payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```